# Python - Regex for all define byte strings in Intel Assembly

Tags: python, regex, assembly

At the moment I'm trying to find all db's in an Intel x86 Assembly File, but now I have the Problem that my regex is somehow wrong and that I may have forgotten a possiblity which can also exist. Here is my current regex, which has the problem that it only matches the first hex string:

```
y+' db ("(?:[^\"]+|\.)*"+),\s*(0x[0-9A-Fa-f]+)*,\s*([0-9])*'
```

y is the name of the byte. For example:

```
name db "Hello World", 0x0D, 0x0A, 0
```

then y is "name". But at the moment it only matches "Hello World", 0x0D and 0, but i want to match 0x0A too. And are there other possiblities which I have forgotten in Intel Assembly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
y+' db ("(?:[^\"]+|\.)*"+),\s*(0x[0-9A-Fa-f]+)*,\s*(0x[0-9A-Fa-f]+),\s*([0-9])*'
```

I only added the same pattern which is set to match `0x0D` with the `0x0A` occurrence

**edit:**

If you want to keep with the old occurrences, this regex

```
y+' db ("(?:[^\"]+|\.)*"+),\s*(0x[0-9A-Fa-f]+)*(?:,\s*(0x[0-9A-Fa-f]+))?,\s*([0-9])*'
```

match with both:

`name db "Hello World", 0x0D, 0x0A, 0`

`name db "Hello World", 0x0D, 0`